# Selecting table depends on textbox value

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview, select

I just created a table programmatically. I named it as my Textbox value.

Example:

```
Create table " & Textbox1.text & " + ......
```

I want to set my table name according to my Textbox value.

```
Select TaskNumber,Name,Age From '" & Textbox1.text & "' "
```

Comment: You're open for SQL-Injection. Consider that the user enters: `TableName'; drop table ImportantTable--`

Comment: Correct syntax in selecting tablename according to my textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

The best pratice would be to put your textbox value in a variable:

```
    Dim myTableName As String
    myTableName = TexBox1.text

    // SQL Connection
    Dim conStr As String = "Server=MyServer;Database=Mydatabase;Trusted_Connection = yes"
    Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    Dim obj As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL as String
    obj = objConn.CreateCommand()

    // *************** Select statement *********
    strSQL = "SELECT TaskNumber, Name, Age FROM " & myTableName

    // **************** Create statement *********
    strSQL = "CREATE TABLE " & myTableName & "(" & _
    "Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, " & _
    "ColumnTest VARCHAR(30)) "

    // Execute the command
    obj.CommandText = strSQL
    obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Just try a SELECT * FROM myTableName

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim query AS String = "Select TaskNumber,Name,Age From " & Textbox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'","")
```

**.Replace("'","")** will prevent SQL-Injection attack due to the presence of single quotes in the TextBox text.

**I will suggest you using *RegularExpressionValidator* on your TextBox to limit the allowed characters.**